# steady state output transfer function

Tags: control-theory

Hi If I'm given an input:

$$r(t) = 2 \sin(3t).$$

And If I'm supposed to get the steady state response $$y(t)$$

for the given transfer function

$$G(s) = \frac{1}{(s+1)(s+1)}$$

Is the following correct:

$$|G(jw)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{w^2+1}\sqrt{w^2+1}}$$

$$y(t)  = \frac{2 \sin(3t + \arctan(3)+\arctan(3))}{10}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have $r(t) = {1 \over i } (e^{i 3t} - e^{-i3t})$, hence the
steady state output is
$y(t) = {1 \over i } (G(3i) e^{i 3t} - G(-3i) e^{-i3t}) = {2 \over 2i } (G(3i) e^{i 3t} - \overline{G(3i) e^{i3t}} ) = 2 \operatorname{im} (G(3i) e^{i 3t})$.

Evaluating gives $y(t) = - {1 \over 25} (3 \cos (3t) + 4 \sin (3t))$.

If we let $\phi = \arctan {3 \over 4}$, we have
$y(t) = -2 {1 \over 10} \sin (3t + \phi) = 2 {1 \over 10} \sin (3t + \phi-\pi)$.

Since $\arctan {3 \over 4} + 2\arctan 3 = \pi$, we have
$y(t) = 2 {1 \over 10} \sin (3t - 2\arctan 3)$.

Comment: Unless I have made a computational error...

Comment: Shouldn't it be positive and our answers look pretty similar. Are you sure mine is wrong?

Comment: Both might be correct, let me check...

Comment: Alright Thank you very much!

Comment: @user108698: Sorry, dinner called. I think you have a sign error.

Comment: Each term ${1 \over 1+s}$ contributes $- \arctan 3$ to the phase...

Comment: Oh I always thought it was plus the phase shift... hmmm alright thanks for the help!

Comment: ${1 \over 1+3i} = {1 - 3i \over 10}$, so it is not hard to see (draw $1-3i$) that the phase shift is negative.

Comment: If the answer is to your liking, it is customary to give US$1,000 to the answerer or accept the answer :-). Well, i might have made the first one up.

Comment: Oh Im new to this site? Whats your banking info? And how do I accept your answer?

Comment: :-). I'm not sure how to accept the answer, maybe you need more rep. I take Bitcoin. (Just kidding!)

Comment: :-) ${}{}{}{}{}$